# Where do I find soft key icons?

Tags: android, icons

I want to use soft key icons such as Back key (return to previous screen), Home key and Display recent apps key in some of the messages to the users (They tend not to know much about using Android). Can someone please tell me where I can find these icons. I am using Android Ice cream sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android-sdks provide the source files installed API versions, there you can find the system resources. You can also refer to them inside your application by android.R.drawable.ic_... but it is not recommended.

Comment: Do you mean directory such as ..\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\drawable-hdpi. I have looked in all these directories but haven't been able to locate these soft keys. There are somewhat similar menu icons there. But not the ones that appear on the screen.

Comment: mdpi is the folder containing all sources.. the other just supply other sizes for specific sources

Comment: I have checked all folders including mdpi. Its not there.